# PHP if statement does not work

Tags: php

I have written a code where a value is got from mysql and if it is 1 then row should be in red colour and if it is 0 the row should be in green colour. When I execute the code it always goes to the else statement.

Code is as below:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $bprofit=$row['profit_loss'];
    if ($bprofit == "1") {
        $colour='#FF0000';
    } else  {
        $colour='#31B404';
    }
    echo "<tr bgcolor=$colour>";
    echo "<td>" . $bprofit . "</td>";
}
```

and output is:

1
0
0
all in green colour only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sounds like your $bpropfit is never equal "1" so do a "var_dump($bprofit);" before the "if" and post it

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra p in $bpprofit:

```
if ($bprofit == "1")
```

Comment: Peak of carelessness... Thanks a lot Rick

Comment: @user2028837 You're welcome :-) Don't forget to accept one of these answers to keep your Accept Score in the green zone if you want to be helped with future questions.

Answer (score 1):

change `if ($bpprofit == "1")` to `if ($bprofit == "1")`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the misspelling mentioned in other answers, I think you need to reference the first index of the array like so:

`if ($bprofit[0] == "1") ...`

EDIT

Based on your new code, are you sure the value that is being returned is a string and not numeric? If it is numeric, you would want your `if` statement to look like this:

`if ($bprofit == 1) ...`

Comment: Nevermind - you changed the original code you had posted...

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this it never hurts to use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function and see what the variable actually contains and how you need to access it.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering problems such as the one above, try activating error reporting in PHP. One way to do this is to update php.ini, but since this might affect other projects in which you don't want error reporting, it might be better to activate it when needed.

What's important is that you enable reporting of notices, since they'll appear when you use a variable that hasn't been set.

The code below is a simple example:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($undefined == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

When this page is displayed, a notice will be shown:

> Notice: Undefined variable: undefined in
>   /var/www/test/undefined_example.php on line 3

Of course, this might not be a suitable solution for all problems, but it might help you figure out where to look.

It might also make you a better programmer; by "reminding" you to declare variables with a standard value if they are not always assigned before later use.